# Настройка Atom для C++

Tags: c++, atom

Хочу настроить текстовый редактор Atom для разработки C++ кода, т.к. редактор мне очень нравится. В интернете нашел что нужно поставить плагины: `script`, `autocomplete-clang`, `linter-clang` . Что дальше делать я так и не понял. Я хотел бы использовать CMake, то есть прописывать конфигурацию проекта в CMakeLists.txt и потом как-то одной кнопочкой делать build и запускать :).

Comment: Что дальше делать? Всё, разрабатывать :) Вопрос очень неконкретный, и я понимаю, что вы пока не в курсе, что в Atom может быть полезного -- возможно, вам стоит сходить на форум Атома и поискать/создать тему с подборкой пакетов для С++. А по этому вопросу -- вас интересует, как из Atom делать билд одной кнопкой?

Comment: > А по этому вопросу -- вас интересует, как из Atom делать билд одной кнопкой?
Можно и так сказать :) 
Меня интересует как подключить MinGW к Atom, что бы при нажатии F9 у меня компилировались исходники и запускался исполняемый файл.

Comment: Например с Rust'ом у меня всё получилось довольно быстро. Скачал build плагин, cargo, сделал через cargo проект и через F9 запустил — получил результат. Тут сборкой занимается cargo. Мне бы как-то также для С++, тут сборкой занимается make на основе makefiles.

Comment: Тогда **отделите** этот вопрос от остального (есть шикарная чёрточка-разделитель `---`), ибо остальное оффтопик. Вполне возможно, что отвечающие расскажут и об этом, но только в дополнение к ответу на основной вопрос. А пока [гляньте на этот пакет](https://atom.io/packages/build-make).

Comment: Его я установил. И просто build тоже установил. Что дальше-то..

Comment: По идее -- всё, можно пользоваться.

Comment: Как запустить проект-то? :) 
У меня открыт простой проект: main.cpp, CMakeLists.txt (и соответствующие инструкции в нём). Как передать этот проект в cmake, а потом в make прямо из редактора?

Comment: Сочетания клавиш по умолчанию [на странице пакета `build`](https://atom.io/packages/build). С CMake -- вопрос, ждём ответов. В крайнем случае, придётся сделать файл с командой, которую нужно дёргать для сборки.

Comment: Эта клавиша по умолчанию — F9. И я получаю: `Failed to build. Cannot read property 'exec' of undefined`

Comment: Это не выглядит, как проблема с настройкой, больше похоже на баг, с которым тоже не сюда. .-.

Comment: Просто нет слов .-.

Comment: К сожалению, у Атома есть известные проблемы со стабильностью пакетов. До релиза ещё и API часто менялся, так что поддержка превращалась в кошмар.

Answer (score 5):

Для начала вам надо научится собирать свой проект в консоли командами `cmake` и `make` (ну в соответствии с вашим компилятором-языком команда `make` будет отличатся, это уже другой вопрос)
После этого вы настраиваете пакет `build` создав в корне каталога проекта файл `.atom-build.json` и прописав там свою `make` команду. Ну и дальше уже `F9` и проблемы линковки, переменной `path` и так далее :). Просто на данном этапе версии продукта не получится, надо ждать совершенствования.
`cmake` вы будете выполнять отдельно в командной строке по мере необходимости (реально это будет редко)